# Please remember to vote, It doesn't cost Money!

Tags: discussion, voting

Voting on Stack Exchange sites does a number of things. It rewards the content that we like to see when we upvote. It also signals trust, the more someone is upvoted, the more powers on the stackexchange site they get.

If we want this site to be successful, those of us that use it on a regular basis need to be upvoting the content we really like and downvoting what we dislike. This gets newer users more involved, and helps spread the responsibility of keeping the site up and running.

So please, remember to vote. It does a site good.

*Note: Stolen words from [Movies & TV Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/987/please-remember-to-vote).*

Comment: This was stated [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hindunism-se?cb=1) already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more thing to remember is to justify downvotes.

Plainly doing a downvote, and going away is not a very nice deed.

***ANYONE WHO DOWNVOTES, PLEASE LEAVE A COMMENT BELOW THE POST ON HOW IT CAN BE IMPROVED***.

**Flagging** is another area in which everyone should take part. Whenever you see content requiring moderator attention, flag it.

Also remember, when you see some mistakes (like spelling, grammatical or otherwise), remember to **suggest an edit**. <sup>1</sup>

If the edit is too minor, leave a comment below the post to notify the OP to do it.

*All these features exist because of a reason, please use them.*

<sub>1. Please see [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/85/75) for suggested edits.</sub>