# Can we please have a "proper" system of "suggesting" edits?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I am constantly getting edit suggestion on my posts. I am not offending those who suggest them, I would rather like to thank all of them by this post.

Although they all are meant to improve the quality of the post, the problem is that some of them change the meaning of the post, many are useless. But, most all of them are a **mix up of constructiveness and de-constructiveness.**

In that case, I can't completely approve them or completely reject them. Then while improving them, we have the option to mark whether the original edit was helpful or not.

This brings in lot of unnecessary trouble.

What I recommend is, that the editor should not *think* that his edit *has to be useful*.

If you see spelling mistakes, correct them right away.

If you see grammatical errors, **think twice before editing because it can change the meaning of the sentence.** Only edit if you are sure it does not change the meaning of what OP is saying.

If you think something else is wrong with the answer, **comment below the post**. This is a sure shot way of helping. Describe in the detail which part is wrong, then OP can either clarify, or edit the post himself, or tell you to edit the post.

Nice examples of such comments were wonderfully demonstrated by user Keshav Srinivasan [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-difference-between-god-and-devi-devta-or-are-they-same/369#comment986_369).

Again, I am not telling anyone to stop suggesting edits, just keep in mind that you are given the option to edit anyone's post only so that you exercise it righteously and only one you are sure that your edit shall help.

Otherwise, commenting is the best option.

Please pour in your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

It is also explained in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlink